# Why is Axios returning an error with Google Place API, when postman isnt?

Tags: javascript, axios, postman

I'm trying to search for nearby locations by first getting the last coordinates with geocode() then inserting it to nearbySearch() to find locations near it. On the console I'm meat with an Axios error:

//Error
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=29.7162525,-95.4169039&radius=500&key=AjzaSyD7LSZB-~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

scripts.js:88 q {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

xhr.js:247          GET [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=29.7162525,-95.4169039&radius=500&key=AjzaSyD7LSZB-~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=29.7162525,-95.4169039&radius=500&key=AjzaSyD7LSZB-%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E%7E)~ net::ERR_FAILED 200

However, when I place the https to Postman, there is no error and everything is working as expected.
What are some potential issue?

//JS code

```
let lastCoordinates

function geocode(){
  axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
    params:{
      address: lastAddress,
      key:'AjzaSyD7LSZB-~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    endAddress = response.data.results[0].geometry.location;
    lastCoordinates = endAddress.lat + "," + endAddress.lng;
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  })
}

nearbyBtn = document.getElementById('nearbyBtn');
nearbyBtn.addEventListener('click', nearbySearch);

// Not working //
function nearbySearch(){
  axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json', {
    params:{
      location: lastCoordinates,
      radius: 500,
      key:'AjzaSyD7LSZB-~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

I tried placing a coordinate on location instead of a lastCoordinates. Maybe the issue was with the variable format. Same thing.

I tried putting the https on Postman to see if the error was with the url/credentials. My key was correct and the information was as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)